# List of Differentiable Ops in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a master list of Tensorflow ops that are differentiable (i.e., will auto-differentiate)?

Two other ways to phrase this:

- List of ops that do not have `ops.NoGradient` set.
- List of ops that will not trigger `LookupError`.

For example, I'd assume that all the Control Flow ops are not differentiable (e.g., `tf.where`). How would I find this other than by manually running them all through `tf.gradients` to see if they throw the `LookupError`.

"Commonsense" is not a valid answer.

Thanks.

EDIT:

`tf.where` is differentiable so my intuitions are wrong. Perhaps the correct question here is which ops in Tensorflow are *not* differentiable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no list (you can be the first one to create it). Also as far as I am aware, documentation of each function also does not tell it ([`tf.size`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/size) is non-differentiable but does not tell about it).

Apart from the way you suggested, you can also extract this data from the source code. For example all the ops that have gradient implemented, have [`@ops.RegisterGradient`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e9de087fa7f59c39bbe12ac2c83c5547c83f746c/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py#L80) in front of the method declaration. For ops which do not have gradient you will have [`ops.NotDifferentiable(`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/state_grad.py#L30)

Not related, but [probably helpful](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/NoGradient).

Answer (score 15):

I have devised the entire list of Differentiable and Non-Differentiable Ops using python code.

You will find the compact list here. Also the code which generated it.

https://github.com/Mainak431/List-of-Differentiable--OPs-and-Non-differentiable-OPs--in-Tensorflow

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Its huge amount of text. The answer will be huge. Near about 800+ lines.

Comment: Thanks so much for this work! Scanning your list saved me much time over scanning through the ever-bloating tensorflow source code.

Comment: kindly, what does differentiable Ops and Non-differentiable Ops means, could anyone help to understand these terms please?

Comment: The list at that link contains several mistakes. For example, it states that `argmax` is differentiable, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that, for TensorFlow 2, such a list is available in the [documentation for the `tf.raw_ops` module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops).